# Elasticsearch date histogram aggregations with min/max/avg

Tags: elasticsearch

Using elasticsearch 5.2.

My data format is next:

```
{
    "_id": "635636", 
    "_index": "test", 
    "_source": {
        "ad_id": 9368, 
        "body": 1,
        "drivetrain": 1, 
        "engine_capacity": 1, 
        "fuel_type": 1, 
        "has_exchange": false, 
        "id": 635636, 
        "manufacturer_id": 12, 
        "model_id": 10, 
        "odometer_state": 110000, 
        "price_byn": 22802, 
        "price_usd": 12000, 
        "source": 2, 
        "source_date": "2016-10-06", 
        "source_id": "12194309", 
        "state": 2, 
        "state_date": "2017-03-07", 
        "transmission_type": 1, 
        "year": 2012
    }, 
    "_type": "ads", 
    "_version": 4, 
    "found": true
}
```

I am trying to get get min/max/avg aggregations by date. Using next query:

```
{
    "size":0,
    "aggs":{
        "avg_price_per_day":{
            "date_histogram":{
                "field":"state_date",
                "interval":"day"
            },
            "aggs":{
                "prices":{
                    "avg":{
                        "field":"price_usd"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "max_price_per_day":{
            "date_histogram":{
                "field":"state_date",
                "interval":"day"
            },
            "aggs":{
                "prices":{
                    "max":{
                        "field":"price_usd"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "min_price_per_day":{
            "date_histogram":{
                "field":"state_date",
                "interval":"day"
            },
            "aggs":{
                "prices":{
                    "min":{
                        "field":"price_usd"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "max_daily_price":{
            "max_bucket":{
                "buckets_path":"max_price_per_day>prices"
            }
        },
        "min_daily_price":{
            "min_bucket":{
                "buckets_path":"min_price_per_day>prices"
            }
        },
        "avg_daily_price":{
            "max_bucket":{
                "buckets_path":"avg_price_per_day>prices"
            }
        }
    },
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "filter":[
                {
                    "range":{
                        "price_usd":{
                            "gt":0
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term":{
                        "manufacturer_id":{
                            "value":11,
                            "boost":1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term":{
                        "model_id":{
                            "value":7,
                            "boost":1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But it returns aggregations only for one month:

```
{
"took":23,
"timed_out":false,
"_shards":{
    "total":1,
    "successful":1,
    "failed":0
},
"hits":{
    "total":6046,
    "max_score":0.0,
    "hits":[

    ]
},
"aggregations":{
    "avg_price_per_day":{
        "buckets":[
            {
                "key_as_string":"2017-01-02",
                "key":1483315200000,
                "doc_count":1494,
                "prices":{
                    "value":4431.045515394913
                }
            },
            {
                "key_as_string":"2017-01-09",
                "key":1483920000000,
                "doc_count":0,
                "prices":{
                    "value":null
                }
            },
            {
                "key_as_string":"2017-01-16",
                "key":1484524800000,
                "doc_count":840,
                "prices":{
                    "value":4299.322619047619
                }
            },
            {
                "key_as_string":"2017-01-23",
                "key":1485129600000,
                "doc_count":3712,
                "prices":{
                    "value":4383.441540948276
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "max_price_per_day":{
        "buckets":[
            {
                "key_as_string":"2017-01-02",
                "key":1483315200000,
                "doc_count":1494,
                "prices":{
                    "value":45000.0
                }
            },
            {
                "key_as_string":"2017-01-09",
                "key":1483920000000,
                "doc_count":0,
                "prices":{
                    "value":null
                }
            },
            {
                "key_as_string":"2017-01-16",
                "key":1484524800000,
                "doc_count":840,
                "prices":{
                    "value":15500.0
                }
            },
            {
                "key_as_string":"2017-01-23",
                "key":1485129600000,
                "doc_count":3712,
                "prices":{
                    "value":45000.0
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "min_price_per_day":{
        "buckets":[
            {
                "key_as_string":"2017-01-02",
                "key":1483315200000,
                "doc_count":1494,
                "prices":{
                    "value":110.0
                }
            },
            {
                "key_as_string":"2017-01-09",
                "key":1483920000000,
                "doc_count":0,
                "prices":{
                    "value":null
                }
            },
            {
                "key_as_string":"2017-01-16",
                "key":1484524800000,
                "doc_count":840,
                "prices":{
                    "value":200.0
                }
            },
            {
                "key_as_string":"2017-01-23",
                "key":1485129600000,
                "doc_count":3712,
                "prices":{
                    "value":200.0
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "max_daily_price":{
        "value":45000.0,
        "keys":[
            "2017-01-02",
            "2017-01-23"
        ]
    },
    "min_daily_price":{
        "value":110.0,
        "keys":[
            "2017-01-02"
        ]
    },
    "avg_daily_price":{
        "value":4431.045515394913,
        "keys":[
            "2017-01-02"
        ]
    }
}
}
```

I have also data for february and march indexed, but it does not included into aggregations. How to include them all?

**UPDATE**

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/avtostat/ads/_search -d '{"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"range":{"state_date":{"gt":"2017-02-01"}}},{"range":{"price_usd":{"gt":0}}},{"term":{"manufacturer_id":{"value":11,"boost":1}}},{"term":{"model_id":{"value":7,"boost":1}}}]}}}'

{
"took":166,
"timed_out":false,
"_shards":{
    "total":1,
    "successful":1,
    "failed":0
},
"hits":{
    "total":6046,
    "max_score":0.0,
    "hits":[
        {
            "_index":"avtostat",
            "_type":"ads",
            "_id":"272894",
            "_score":0.0,
            "_source":{
                "id":272894,
                "ad_id":111602,
                "manufacturer_id":11,
                "model_id":7,
                "fuel_type":3,
                "engine_capacity":1.6,
                "transmission_type":2,
                "year":1999,
                "body":6,
                "drivetrain":1,
                "state":2,
                "odometer_state":303000,
                "has_exchange":true,
                "price_byn":4816,
                "price_usd":2500,
                "state_date":"2017-02-05",
                "source":1,
                "source_id":"3215650",
                "source_date":"2017-02-05"
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have documents for the other months that match your query? Your query returns `"hits":{    "total":6046` matching documents which match the sum of documents from each bucket. Try using [`extended_bounds` and `min_doc_count: 0`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation-extended-bounds) to see if the buckets you are expecting are maybe empty?

Comment: @AndreiStefan thaks for your answer. i have updated my question, you can see that data exists. but even for this filters - 6046 hits. i am confused

Comment: Given the filters in your query, I don't think both your documents that you provided will match, only one of them will. You have `manufacturer_id: 11` but only one document from those two have it. What is your intention with that `bool` query?

Comment: Maybe you want to use a `should` statement instead of a `filter`?

Comment: @AndreiStefan first item is just to demontrate data format. I need to aggregate min/max/avg prices by date for manufacturer and model ids. changing filter to must or should does not affect anything.

Comment: Ok, then. Please, provide a document that is in the list of matched docs and you can see it being aggregated. And another document that you believe **it should be in the results, but it isn't**.

Comment: @AndreiStefan look... in question third code block - response with aggregations. you can see `avg_price_per_day` buckets there. it includes `2017-01-02`, `2017-01-09`, `2017-01-16`, `2017-01-23` keys. and here are two problems: 1) i have installed interval = day, but it uses week as inverval; 2) look at my update block in question, it shows that i have items with `state_date` > 2017-02-01, but why my aggregations does not include this items? it aggregates items only for january . it is maybe difficult to explain or understand

Comment: Are you sure you are querying the right index/cluster? I know it sounds strange, but as you said the query you are showing me doesn't match the results. There should have been some empty buckets for the missing days in there.

Comment: And one more detail: what's the mapping of the `state_date` field?

Comment: Same question for the query: are you sure the query you are sending to ES is the one you posted here? As you said, that data is with `interval: week` and if you say there should be data from other months as well, it seems the data is also filtered.

Comment: How do you query this cluster? `curl`, some application, kibana, something else?

Comment: @AndreiStefan thanks for replying. 1 - i am sure that i quering right index, changed manually in 1 code block to hide index name) 2 - `"state_date":{"type":"date","format":"YYYY-MM-DD"}`. 3 - tryed with curl and php client, no difference. 4 - is it filtered by default? because it is not filtered in query https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-date-histogram-aggregations-with-min-max-avg/81355

Comment: Your date format is incorrect. See [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) what the capital letters mean as opposed to the small letters (`yyyy-MM-dd`). Especially the `D` has a significantly different meaning here. Change the format to the above one, re-index your data and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format is incorrect. See [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) what the capital letters mean as opposed to the small letters (`yyyy-MM-dd`). So, what you need ot `yyyy-MM-dd` and not `YYYY-MM-DD`. Especially the `D` has a significantly different meaning here:

> Symbol      Meaning                              Presentation      Examples
>
> D                    day of year                     number                    189
>
> d                    day of month                  number                   10

This is a relevant example of what I mean:

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "state_date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "YYYY-MM-DD"
        },
        "some_id": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/test/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"some_id":272894,"state_date":"2017-08-05"}
{"index":{}}
{"some_id":272894,"state_date":"2017-08-04"}
{"index":{}}
{"some_id":272894,"state_date":"2017-08-03"}
{"index":{}}
{"some_id":272894,"state_date":"2017-08-09"}
{"index":{}}
{"some_id":272894,"state_date":"2017-10-12"}

GET /test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "avg_price_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "state_date",
        "interval": "day"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, in my test you see days from August and October 2017. But, according to the documentation and format of the day (capital `D`) the days numbers are days of year, not days of months, which means that `08-05` is the fifth day of 2017, not of August. `08-09` is the 9th day of 2017 and not of August and so on.

Which means that all your days are, in fact, days of January. As you can see from the result of the aggregations:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "avg_price_per_day": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-01-03",
          "key": 1483401600000,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-01-04",
          "key": 1483488000000,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-01-05",
          "key": 1483574400000,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-01-06",
          "key": 1483660800000,
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-01-07",
          "key": 1483747200000,
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-01-08",
          "key": 1483833600000,
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-01-09",
          "key": 1483920000000,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-01-10",
          "key": 1484006400000,
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-01-11",
          "key": 1484092800000,
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2017-01-12",
          "key": 1484179200000,
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```